# Call JWT refresh token API on each angular component loads

Tags: asp.net, angular, session, jwt

In our existing asp.net application we are using session which increase the timeout db column during each page load. And now developing new pages using angular which part of asp.net apps(inside asp.net app with navigation. it's a requirement). In angular i am using jwt token. In asp.net application, during page load refreshing both Session and JWT token (called api and stored in cookie with ajax). Here i stuck. i want to refresh both session and jwt token. i wrote api for this but i don't know how to call that api from angular during each components load and event trigger (eg. edit, save, delete etc).

Calling api during auth check but some components using multiple apis. Hence token refreshing multiple times

Need to call api only once per transaction (eg: component load, submit form etc). But if i write in appropriate place then lot of duplicate code will impact. So expecting to write in app.component file.

Comment: You can call in ngInit() method of component.
`@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // ...
  }
}`

Comment: I tried it. But then the API got called first time app.components load. But i expect to call api on each event. Ex: Save form, Component Load

Comment: You can user angular interceptor https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8